# Slack api/chat.attachmentAction gives Error

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am working on one slack app where interactive buttons are used which is working properly but during command invocation, i found such kind of error in my console window. I search a lot but Can't find any information on the error.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: slackError]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you to always add images inline in the questions instead of URL. For editing and formatting help visit here https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: This looks like an internal error of the Slack browser app, which does not have to be related to anything you are doing. Are you getting any error from the API or is your Slack app not performing as expected? Best to send this to Slack directly.